# Can I prevent unwanted items from appearing more than once in the same playthrough?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

It happens every time!  I go to the item room and find Teleport.  I don't need Teleport, so I leave it.  Then the next item I find is *another Teleport!*  This will happen either in the challenge room on the same level or in the next item room.  I thought I made it clear that I **don't want Teleport.**  Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

Note that this happens with unwanted items besides Teleport.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "drops" are completely random. There is no way you can force an item to NOT drop, but you can mitigate your chances of getting a duplicate:

- unlock everything you can. Characters' primary and secondary secret items, secret bosses, basically you have to play A LOT. Having to choose from a pool of 20 items is different from having to choose between 130.
- unlock the D6 by:

  > beating the Womb with [???](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/???) (that is unlocked by beating the game 10 times)

This item lets you re-roll your unwanted items and with some clever combinations and tricks, grants you almost any item you want.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to force it not to spawn again in that playthrough.

If you collect an upgrade, it stops spawning until you start a new game, so the way to stop teleport from spawning again is to collect it, and then get your old activated item back.

Answer (score 3):

Pick the item up, then pick up your old item again. Touching a space bar item will remove it from the drop pools for a run.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know item drops are totally random so, as I see it one of 2 things is happening.
1.You just have really bad luck and keep getting the same item
2.Your game is glitched and keeps spawning teleport.

EDIT: Reinstalling your game may fix this error.

Comment: I have to say that I too have never seen such a phenomenon in any of my many playthroughs...

Comment: It happens with more than just teleport.  It's just always items I do not want.

Comment: Sounds like [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) then. If you really want to be rigorous start up a spreadsheet and write down everything you find; keeping it all in your head leads to remembering the five times you got Teleport and forgetting the ten times you got other stuff.

Comment: Kappei's answer is also correct. The drops are random but can be randomized with a certain item. other then that there is nothing you can do.

Comment: @Tacroy I am getting them in the same playthrough.  There is no confirmation bias.

Answer (score 0):

If you pick up an an item and then put it back and leaving it (you can surely do it with Teleport) , it won't spawn again for the rest of the run until you die but you may find it in the next run you have :)